# Single particle state in $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I'm quite happy with the idea that a multi-particle state in a free scalar field theory has a discrete energy spectrum, and that turning on a quartic coupling $\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4$ acts as a perturbation, shifting this spectrum.

Furthermore, we can interpret this $\phi^4$ term as an interaction. In the two-particle state, we can for instance compute $\langle n\left|\phi^4(x)\right|m\rangle$, to get the amplitude of the $\phi^2$ operator annihilating a two-particle state $|m\rangle$ and creating another one, $|n\rangle$.

How does a quartic coupling in scalar field theory affect one-particle states, and how do we interpret this?